# How do I search a list of numbers for duplicates and drop the first of 2 duplicated values by 1?

Tags: python, excel, list, duplicates

I get a list of numbers 90 - 480; this range is not completely filled. What I mean is that the list may be 90, 91, 92, 94, 95...and so on up to 480 and the missing 93 is expected. Every time I get the list there are lots of duplicates. Also, I might get up to 10 lists at a time. What I do know about the list is that if there are duplicates, 100% of the time, if I drop the first of the 2 duplicates by 1 value, then continue scanning for duplicates this will give me an accurate list. the list might look like: '90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 95, 96, 98, 100, 100, 102, 102.....' so to get this part of the list accurate I will need to change the first 95 to 94, the first 100 to 99, and the first 102 to 101.

Sorry if I am asking in the incorrect place but just for the sake of this question; the list is in excel but I could use Python or Linux as I have access to both of those as well. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have code you've tried yet?

Comment: its not very clear what your question actually is ...

Comment: Stack overflow is for helping not for performing school tasks

Comment: _3.  Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ -[Help Center: What's On Topic Here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: No code. I think it's clear - Take a list that contains duplicates, of the duplicates, drop the first duplicate by a value of 1. It's not schoolwork. Also, in the past I have asked similar questions and received answers. TOS change? Thanks

Comment: How about: `for i in range(90,481): print i`

Comment: It's actually not that clear, do you want the same list only without duplicates? Do you want to fill the missing numbers? If there are more than one duplicate do you want to remove them all or just the first? What is the result you are expecting? Given this list: [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,6,7,7,10] what would your ideal output be?

Comment: @Aquiles Same list but have the duplicates only change. So if the duplicate in the list was '90, 90' it would change to '89, 90'. Missing numbers are ok. Change all the duplicates in the same way I just stated. The result will be a list with the duplicates being changed to consecutive numbers by dropping the first of the 2 duplicate numbers by 1. Your given list would not apply. Also, no triplicates. But changing your example to [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10] my ideal output for that would be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Thank you so much.

Comment: what about [1,2,2] would that be a possible input?

Comment: No. because the duplicate 2's would not exist in the list as the 1 is there.

Comment: so...the output would be [1,2] if we were to use example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> i = 0
>>> a = [1,3,3,4,6,6]
>>> numbers = []
>>> while i < len(a):
...     if a.count(a[i]) == 1: numbers.append(a[i]); i += 1
...     else: numbers.append(a[i]-1); a.remove(a[i])
... 
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This will give you your desired output, I bet there is a better way to do it but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach based on the [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=tee#recipes) recipe:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

numbers = [90, 91, 92, 93, 95, 95, 96, 98, 100, 100, 102, 102]
fixed = []
a, b = tee(numbers)
next(b, None)

for x, y in izip(a, b):
    if x == y:
        x -= 1
    fixed.append(x)
fixed.append(y)        

print fixed
```

This would display:

```
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102]
```